# Sorting a dictionary by value from greatest to least

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

The code I have is:

```
sAreaOfCountries=sorted(aOfCountries.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

But this sorts from least to greatest. How would I sort from greatest to least?

Comment: Please add a sample of what your dictionary looks like. We can't help you if you don't show your code.

Comment: use `reverse=True`

Comment: pass `reverse=True` to sorted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sorted` has an argument called `reverse`.

```
sAreaOfCountries=sorted(aOfCountries.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
```

Comment: And if it were a list of dictionaries, sorting them by a value would be ```sorted(all_countries_list, key=lambda d: d["key"], reverse=True)```